# How to run Jest test cases with Vanilla JS?

Tags: jestjs, babel-jest

I am trying to run test cases using jest with vanilla javascript.

**login.test.js**

```
import { validateEmail } from '../assets/js/common';

describe('validate email', () => {
    it('should pass with valid email', () => {
        const result = validateEmail('example@test.com');
        expect(result).toBe(true);    
    });
    it('should fail with invalid email', () => {
        const result = validateEmail('exampletest.com');
        expect(result).toBe(false);    
    });
})
```

**common.js**

```
export const validateEmail = (email) => {
    return email && EMAIL.test(email);
}
```

When I run `npm run test`, it is throwing

> ```
> ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){
> ```
>
> import { validateEmail } from '../assets/js/common';
>
> ```
>            ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
> ```

I followed many threads on GitHub but no use. They are saying about React, react-native, and also Babel config etc. But I don't have any **.babelrc** in my project. It's just html, css, pug, js and webpack.

Below is my project directory structure.

[image]

Comment: Any luck on solving this?

Comment: Oh I forgot. Follow the link mentioned in the answer. Try, hope it works

Answer (score 2):

Es6 modules require babel. To set up babel with jest follow https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started.html#using-babel, create the .babelrc as per the guide, and remove all react related parts since you don't use react here.